# Button not disappearing on multiple views using common div id in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on a .NET MVC application. I have added a button using jQuery using the following code:

```
var button_to_add = '<div id = "csv_button"><nav>CSV</nav></div>'
$("#titleDiv").append(button_to_add);
```

The problem is multiple views are using the "titleDiv" and each view is rendered through javascript. As a result, the button is appearing on all the views. The view slides in when another link is clicked. I could remove the button using:

```
$("#csv_button").remove();
```

But I am not sure how and when to call it so that the button disappears when the view slides off.

Edit: I am looking for a javascript call that will detect when the view starts sliding so that the button can be removed at that moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are saying `titleDiv` is use for multiple view then use it as a `class` rather than an `id`.

And you should have `unique id's` for each element if at all you are using id's.
so your expression will become:

```
var button_to_add = '<div id = "csv_button"><nav>CSV</nav></div>'
$(".titleDiv").append(button_to_add);
```

Answer (score 0):

IDs in HTML cannot be reused.  The browsers will accept it, but you jQuery will only look at the first one.

Use a distinct ID to allow for clean, single append.